# How do I update to Apache 2.4.44 and later on CentOS 6.10?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

Currently, `yum info httpd` displays the following:

```
$ yum info httpd

Loaded plugins: aliases, changelog, fastestmirror, kabi, presto, refresh-packagekit, security, tmprepo, verify, versionlock
Loading support for CentOS kernel ABI
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos-lax.psychz.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: mirror.chpc.utah.edu
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mirror.centos.lax1.serverforge.org
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
 * updates: mirror.arizona.edu
 
Installed Packages
Name        : httpd
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.2.15
Release     : 69.el6.centos
Size        : 3.0 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The Apache HTTP Server is a powerful, efficient, and extensible web server.
```

Although it still wasn't the right version, I was able to update to Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat), or so I thought? Upon rebooting, it reverted back to 2.2.15

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: you did install Apache 2.4 but you're querying it incorrectly. The proper command will be:

```
yum info httpd24
```

---

Now onto the explanation: the latest version of the Apache web server (the `httpd` package) for CentOS 6.10 is `2.2.15-69`. No newer versions are available as an official update.

You can install Apache version 2.4 which has a different package name, `httpd24`, via a separate software collections repository:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install httpd24 httpd24-httpd httpd24-mod_ssl
```

The list of available packages in the SCL can be found here [List of Software Collections available in SCLo SIG](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/SCLo/CollectionsList)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The issue that I'm having now is that trying to install httpd24 gives me the message that "Package httpd24-1.1-19.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version. Nothing to do". Also, yum info httpd24 tells me that it is version 1.1

Comment: If it's installed use it. `rpm -ql httpd24` will allow to see its files.

Comment: Using that command shows "contains no files"! Before doing the yum install commands, was I supposed to navigate to a certain directory to ensure they were installed correctly?

Comment: @glad Just wanted to make sure you knew that Centos 6 is End Of Life November 30, 2020?  It might not be the best place to start a new project. [centos specifications](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product)

Comment: @jsbillings your (appropriate) EOL notice is probably more appropriately placed on the Question vs an Answer.

Comment: Artem and @glad: clarifications of the question are best done on the Question, not on an Answer. Thank you!